# GPARs async functions and passing references that are being updated by another thread

Tags: gpars

I am using GPARs asynchronous functions to fire off a process as each line in a file is parsed.

I am seeing some strange behavior that makes me wonder if I have an issue with thread safety.

Let's say I have a current object that is being loaded up with values from the current row in an input spreadsheet, like so:

```
Uploader {
  MyRowObject currentRowObject
}
```

Once it has all the values from the current row, I fire off an async closure that looks a bit like this:

```
Closure processCurrentRowObject = { ->
    myService.processCurrentRowObject (currentRowObject)
}.asyncFun()
```

It is defined in the same class, so it has access to the currentRowObject.

While that is off and running, I parse the next row, and start by creating a new object:

```
MyObject currentObject = new MyObject()
```

and start loading it up with values.

I assumed that this would be safe, that the asynchronous function would be pointing to the previous object.  However, I wonder if because I am letting the closure bind to the reference, if somehow the reference is getting updated in the async function, and I am pulling the object instance out from under it, so to speak - changing it while it's trying to work on the previous instance.

If so, any suggestions for fixing?  Or am I safe?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your case, however, here's a quick tip.
Since it is always dangerous to share a single mutable object among threads, I'd recommend to completely separate the row objects used for different rows:

final localRowObject = currentRowObject
currentRowObject = null

Closure processCurrentRowObject = { ->
    myService.processCurrentRowObject (localRowObject)
}.asyncFun()

Comment: Thanks... it was just a bit trickier, I was creating a new object for each row, but the reference to that current object was a member variable.  I changed it to make a copy of the object before calling (essentially) processCurrentRowObject(), and pass in that copy.  I guess in my mind, I thought of the closure as a function unto itself, as long as it wasn't internally referencing things external to it and all was being passed in.  In general, I've done a good job at isolating things within closures with a functional mindset, but I think the groovy closure binding got me here.

Comment: @Vaclav... one follow up question, if you don't mind... is the answer in this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529521/how-do-i-execute-two-tasks-simultaneously-and-wait-for-the-results-in-groovy?rq=1) really the best way to go to wait for a bunch of async functions to finish?  It could be tens of thousands.  Thanks!

Comment: I went ahead and posted my follow up as a separate question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405806/gpars-report-status-on-large-number-of-async-functions-and-wait-for-completion

Comment: Just as a further note to any poor schleps that find their way here... I isolated this problem in a standalone test.  If I pass in the variable to the closure, everything is fine - I make the async function sleep, change the reference in the main thread to point a new object, and the async function still uses the original object.  If however, I don't pass the variable (currentRowObject) into the closure but reference the Uploader's member variable directly inside the closure, a change to it in the main thread does take affect (i.e., the async function picks up the new object from the ref).

Comment: It's more obvious now that I think about it, but I wanted to be sure that passing it into the closure was safe, and it is (if you change the sample code above to something like this):

Comment: Closure processCurrentRowObject = { passedRowObject ->
        myService.processCurrentRowObject (passedRowObject )
    }.asyncFun()